# How and what would I get from a car rain sensor?

Tags: obd-ii

I am looking for an answer on how to acquire data for the vehicle rain sensor and automatic wiper data from any vehicle.

For example I know that with Carberry (a raspberry pi) it provides a lot of OBD features, however, I cannot seem to find anything on acquiring data for rain sensor, precipitation, wiper frequency, wiper speed...

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Many thanks for any help that is given.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about software.

Comment: it would be more helpful giving advice on where to post it in all respect. Offer the solution to avoid repetition. I did try looking myself couldn't find an exact spot on where to post it so help is appreciated. Furthermore, people may have insight as it's regarding data...

Comment: I'd try https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you much appreciated

Comment: The question would be more suitable on mechanics.stackexchange.com